# Make Django admin ManyToMany field filter_horizontal searchable on both sides?

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

Is there a way to make a ManyToMany field that uses filter_horizontal text searchable from both sides. By default the left side is searchable but the right is not.

[image]